# can't require ruby aws-s3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I am using marcel's `aws-s3` gem. I'm trying to require it in my project:

`gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'`

However, it doesn't get required:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'aws/s3'
=> false
```

How can I get rid of the `AWS::S3::` namespace?

Comment: If you are using Bundler, the `:require` part in the Gemfile already should require the gem. Requiring it again manually will then return `false`. Try it with something from the stdlib, e.g. start IRB and `require 'set'` twice in a row.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, in my code it doesn't recognize classes without prefixing it with `AWS::S3::`.

Comment: Well, that's probably because the classes are defined inside the `S3` module inside the `AWS` module. As you'll notice, the docs use `AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!` too.... Think namespacing if you come from another language and aren't too familiar with Ruby.

Comment: Isn't the point of require in Gemfile to import it without namespacing? How can I avoid typing `AWS::S3::`?

Comment: The point of `require` in the Gemfile is to require the gem. If the author decided that the classes are namespaced, why should Bundler override that?

Comment: Are you saying that `:require => 'aws/s3'` in Gemfile is different from `require 'aws/s3'`?

Comment: No, I'm saying that it's exactly the same. Now assume for a moment that Bundler would get rid of all the namespacing and you'd use the AWS gem in a Rails app, how'd you distinguish between `AWS::S3::Base` and `ActiveRecord::Base`? If you really still want to get rid of the namespace, `include AWS` and `include S3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bundler, the `:require` part in the Gemfile already should require the gem. Requiring it again manually will then return false. Try it with something from the stdlib, e.g. start IRB and require 'set' twice in a row.

Regarding the `AWS::S3::` part. Assume for a moment that Bundler or `require` would get rid of all the namespacing and you'd use the AWS gem in a Rails app, how'd you distinguish between `AWS::S3::Base` and `ActiveRecord::Base`? If you really still want to get rid of the namespace, `include AWS` and `include S3`.